# Git cannot find my gpg2 file or directory Windows OS

Tags: windows, git, gitlab, gnupg

So I'm trying to sign my commits so that I can eventually send a merge request for the changes I've made.
It requires a gpg key so I downloaded Gpg4Win and generated the public gpg key I needed using Kleopatra and linked that to my GitLab. All the normal steps needed.
I configured git to my key as follows:

```
git config --global user.signingkey 0B613778C578
```

And then tried to commit, signing with the new key:

```
git commit -S -m "Google Tag Manager installed onto 404 error page"
```

Where I receive the following error:

```
gpg: skipped "0B613778C578": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

GitLab advises to use the following when receiving this message:

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg2
```

But that generates the following error:

```
error: cannot spawn gpg2: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

And this is basically where I am at. I have now idea how to get git to point to my gpg properly

This is the version of gpg I have installed:
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19

Any help is greatly appreciated.